# How to detect view collision in a breakout app?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I am working on a Breakout app in swift. I currently have a ball, which is a `UIView` with a `cornerRadius = 20.0` to emulate a ball. I also have a paddle, which is another `UIView` with a smaller `cornerRadius = 5.0`. I have programmatically made nine red views which are each 50x50 units large. I have collision and motion mechanics for my ball, paddle, and block elements.`var dynamicAnimator: UIDynamicAnimator!

```
var pushBehavior: UIPushBehavior!

var collisionBehavior: UICollisionBehavior!

var ballDynamicBehavior: UIDynamicItemBehavior!

var paddleDynamicBehavior: UIDynamicItemBehavior!

var blockBehaviors: UIDynamicItemBehavior!
```

My issue here, is that the ball collides with the blocks, but I don't know how to detect whether or not the ball hit the block, but I do know how to make the views appear and disappear (give the view a backgroundcolor matching the View's color, and remove it from the blockBehaviors. Basically, I want to know how to detect when two views collide via. function or something else.

It would also be awesome if I could also add multiple levels,lol.

Answer (score 0):

A `UICollisionBehavior` needs a delegate that adopts the `UICollisionBehaviorDelegate` protocol. This delegate has a method `collisionBehavior` that is called whenever a collision is detected.

For example:

```
var collisionBehavior: UICollisionBehavior!       // create a UICollisionBehavior as you have done
collisionBehavior.addItem(ball)                   // add your items to it
collisionBehavior.addItem(block)                  // (faster to do this in the init step with `items` argument)
collisionBehavior.collisionDelegate = myDelegate  // give it a delegate which adopts UICollisionBehaviorDelegate
dynamicAnimator.addBehavior(collisionBehavior)    // add the behavior to your animator
```

Then implement `func collisionBehavior` for your delegate class. Often people just use the `UIViewController` itself as the delegate, so the above line would read `collisionBehavior.collisionDelegate = self`.

See "Making objects respond to collisions" here for a good and short tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76147/uikit-dynamics-tutorial-swift.